# Frame for "Banner View" will be different at run time. iAd works for largest screen but blank on smaller ones

Tags: ios, frame, iad, adbannerview

I've nearly finished my app and the only issue I have is that my iAd banner view will only show on the largest screen.
I have set the constraints so the iAd will fit nicely on smaller screens but when I run it on any size other than the largest, all I see is a white box.

The current code I have is:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

I'm wondering if I should add a line of code to the `bannerViewDidLoadAd` to say something about the frame size.

The error I keep getting is:

```
Frame for "banner view" will be different at run time.
```

Size will be (320,50) at runtime but is (480,60) in the canvas.

The iAd framework has been imported and the add delegated.
It's within a scroll view if that makes any difference.

All my constraints are fine it's just this frame size that's the issue. if i attempt to update frames nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have trailing and leading constraints set on your `ADBannerView`.

Your `ADBannerView` will know which device it is on and set the dimensions of the `ADBannerView` accordingly. You should just let Auto Layout know where you want your ad to be. For example, if you wanted your `ADBannerView` to be at the bottom of your view then you would pin it to the bottom of your view with `Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide` and align it to `Align Center X to: Superview`.

Also, don't use the `beginAnimations:context:` method. From [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/commitAnimations):

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Using block-based animations, your delegate methods would end up looking like this:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        banner.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        banner.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```